# Variables defined in describe is "undefined" in outer functions in angular test (jest/jasmine)

Tags: angular, jestjs, jasmine

I have code like this:

```js
// imports
    
describe('AdminGetRightsComponent', () => {
    
  // Declare variables to be re-initialized before each test suite
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AdminGetRightsComponent>;
  let component: AdminGetRightsComponent;
  let router: Router;
  let location: Location;
  let debugElement: DebugElement;


  window.alert = jest.fn();

  // Create service stubs
  let nxDialogServiceStub: Partial<NxDialogService>;
  nxDialogServiceStub = {};

  let ServicesRmAdminServiceStub: Partial<ServicesRmAdminService>;
  ServicesRmAdminServiceStub = {

    // Simulate API call, wait for 1000 milliseconds
    async getRights(contactIds: string[]) {
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
      return {
        body: TEST_API_RESPONES_BODY
      }
    }
  };

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AdminGetRightsComponent ],
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([{ path: '', component: AdminGetRightsComponent }]),
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        modulesForTests
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: NxDialogService },
        { provide: ServicesRmAdminService, useValue : ServicesRmAdminServiceStub},
        { provide: ServicesFileManagementService }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });


  beforeEach(() => {
    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
    location = TestBed.inject(Location);
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AdminGetRightsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.downloadCSV = jest.fn(() => {
      component.fileUploaderComponent.removeFile(component.files[0]);
    });
    debugElement = fixture.debugElement;
    fixture.ngZone.run(() => {
      router.initialNavigation();
    });
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });


  describe('When uploaded a file', () => {


    beforeEach((done) => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      uploadFileToComponent(component);
      setTimeout(done, TEST_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
    });

    afterEach((done) => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      // Remove the file
      component.files.length > 0 && component.fileUploaderComponent.fileDeleted.emit(component.files[0]);

      setTimeout(done, TEST_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
    });

    it('should have the right UI elements', () => {

      fixture.detectChanges();

      expect(...).toBe(...);
    });

    describe('When clicked on the delete file button', () => {


      beforeEach((done) => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        getNativeElement('nx-file-upload-delete button', debugElement).click();
        setTimeout(done, TEST_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
      });

      it('should remove the right UI elements', () => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(...).toBe(...);
      });

    });

    // other code

  });

});
```

In my code, I have many `beforeEach` like this (at least 8 or 9 places):

```js
beforeEach((done) => {
  fixture.detectChanges();
  getNativeElement('nx-file-upload-delete button', debugElement).click();
  setTimeout(done, TEST_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
});
```

The `fixture.detectChanges()` and `setTimeout(...)` is duplicate of code and I don't want it.

---

At first, I wrote something like this:

```js
function _beforeEach(callback) {
  eval('fixture.detectChanges()');
  beforeEach((done) => {
    callback();
    setTimeout(done, TEST_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
  })
}
```

Then I replaced all the previous `beforeEach` by this `_beforeEach` that can help me reduce 2 lines of code for each call. But it says `ReferenceError: fixture is not defined`.

---

Then I tried something like this:

```js
function _beforeEach(
  callback,
  fixture: ComponentFixture<AdminGetRightsComponent>
) {
  fixture.detectChanges();
  beforeEach((done) => {
    callback();
    setTimeout(done, TEST_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
  });
}
```

And I replaced all the previous `beforeEach` by the `_beforeEach` above, when I launch the tests with `ng test`, I got the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'detectChanges' of undefined`.

---

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: I don't see why you'd expect that _not_ to happen, that's how JavaScript scoping works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you try to archive this:

```js
function _beforeEach(
  callback
) {
  fixture.detectChanges();
  beforeEach((done) => {
    callback();
    setTimeout(done, TEST_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
  });
}
```

while I don't see the need for the line `fixture.detectChanges();`. It seems just duplicating the same code from the root `beforeEach`.

I would also avoid `setTimeout(done, TEST_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);` that would slow down the test run execution time. In most cases `await fixture.whenStable()` solve the issue of waiting for the async operations to finish. If it doesn't enough then `fakeAsyncc` with `tick` or `jasmine.clock` might be a solution. While it doesn't always work and I also once in a while give up and using the timeout solution.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `await fixture.whenStable()`, it's really helpful.